# How to get search value into api string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have stated learning react and tried to make a project that renders data from an api. I have 2 components, a Search bar and a component that renders the weather.

What I'm trying to do is to get the value from the search bar and concatenate into the api string. I have tried doing this by settings a prop but I am unable accessing it in the weather component.

My questions is: How can I access the search value in a different component

*/components/Search.js*

```
 class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
  };


  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchValue(this.state.title);
    this.setState({ title: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Mui.Container>
        <CssBaseline />
        <form
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          autoComplete='off'
        >
          <Mui.Input
            placeholder='enter place'          
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </form>
      </Mui.Container>
    );
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  searchValue: PropTypes.func,
};
```

*/components/Weather.js*

```
class Weather extends Component {
  state = {
    videos: [],
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        '<weather api here>'
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const videosArr = res.data.videos.map((item) => {
          return item;
        });
        this.setState({ videos: videosArr });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
            {this.state.videos.map((video, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={video.id}>
                  <Mui.Grid item>
                    <Mui.Paper>
                      <div>                       
                         <img src='./190x107.png' alt='placeholder' />
                         <div>
                           <a href={video.url}>{video.title}</a>
                         </div> 
                      </div>
                    </Mui.Paper>
                  </Mui.Grid>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there will be a parent component for `<Weather />` and `<Search />`?

If yes then the parent component can have state, and you pass your setState function into the search component, and then you pass the current state into the weather component.

```
<Weather searchValue="current state from parent" />
```

```
class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      videos: []
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
    .get(`URL?${this.props.searchValue}`)
    .then((res) => {
      const videosArr = res.data.videos.map((item) => {
        return item;
      });
      this.setState({ videos: videosArr });
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.videos.map((video, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={video.id}>
            <Mui.Grid item>
              <Mui.Paper>
                <div>                       
                  <img src='./190x107.png' alt='placeholder' />
                  <div>
                    <a href={video.url}>{video.title}</a>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </Mui.Paper>
            </Mui.Grid>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However when I use `{this.props.searchValue}` it doesn't work and when I console.log, it returns undefined.

Comment: I have made an edit to show the change you need to make to when calling the Weather component